# Why is the data connection non-persistent in FTP? What advantage does this offer over keeping it as a persistent connection?

Tags: tcp, ftp, persistent-connection

The control connection in FTP is persistent but the data connection is created and disposed after each data transfer (aka. non-persistent). What are the advantages to making the data connection non-persistent? Does making the data connection non-persistent free up resources for the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that end of file equals end of stream, so that there doesn't have to be a superimposed protocol on the data connection.

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of superimposed protocol on data connection?

Comment: @Zephyr For example, sending the length of the file ahead of the file.